# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have the following table..

```
create table Reservation(
Reservation_number int not null auto_increment,
Flight_id int not null,
Number_of_passengers int,
Contact_Passport_number int,
primary key(Reservation_number),
foreign key(Flight_id) references Flight(Flight_id),
foreign key(Contact_Passport_number) references Contact(Contact_Passport_number)
);
```

.. the following stored procedure

```
delimiter //
create procedure addContact(
    in reservation_nr int,
    in passport_number int,
    in email varchar(30),
    in phone bigint)
begin
    declare PassNumCheck int;
    declare ResNumCheck int;

    select Passengers.Passport_number into PassNumCheck
    from Passengers
    where Passengers.Passport_number = passport_number;

    select Reservation_number into ResNumCheck
    from Reservation
    where Reservation_number = reservation_nr;

    if (ResNumCheck is null) then
        select "The given reservation number does not exist" as message;
    elseif (PassNumCheck is null) then
        select "The person is not a passenger of the reservation" as message;
    else
        insert into Contact(Contact_Passport_number,Phone_number,E_mail)
        values (passport_number,phone,email);

        update Reservation
        set Contact_Passport_number = passport_number
        where Reservation_number = reservation_nr;
    end if;
end;
//
delimiter ;
```

..and the following procedure call

```
CALL addContact(@a,00000001,"frodo@magic.mail",080667989);
```

I am getting the following error " Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Reservation_number' in 'where clause' " when i try to execute the procedure call.

Update..
I also have the following trigger and table

```
drop trigger if exists ticketnumber;
delimiter //
create trigger ticketnumber
after update on Reservation
for each row

begin
declare ticket_number bigint;
set ticket_number=rand();

update Ticket set Ticket_number=ticket_number
where Reservation.Reservation_number=NEW.Reservation_number;
end;
//

delimiter ;

create table Ticket(
Booking_id int not null,
Passport_number int not null,
Ticket_number int,
primary key(Booking_id,Passport_number),
foreign key(Booking_id) references Booking(Booking_id),
foreign key(Passport_number) references Passengers(Passport_number)
);
```

Comment: Which query is the error happening on?

Comment: I get no such error when running this code , do you have any triggers in play?

Comment: @Barmar it's the last statement.. where Reservation_number = reservation_nr;

Comment: @P.Salmon yes i am using a trigger

Comment: The error may be initiated by the trigger fired by the sp..

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? I'd assume that the second trigger is the culprit, as the `Ticket` table has no `Reservation_number` column

Comment: @P.Salmon please refer to the above update. The triggger is created for a different table but it does depend on Reservation_number column of Reservation table.

Comment: @NicoHaase it should be Reservation.Reservation_number. So basically i want a ticket_number to be generated in the Ticket table when a new Reservation_number is generated in the Reservation table.

Comment: So, what have you tried to debug the problem? Anything? Updating the whole ticket table seems pretty strange to me, you should restrict this to some tickets by any condition

Comment: where Reservation.Reservation_number=NEW.Reservation_number; - makes no sense , refering to NEW.reservation_number is fine but the left hand column has to exist in the ticket table And if you want to generate ticket an INSERT would be more appropriate.

Comment: You need a `JOIN` that relates `Ticket` to `Reservation`.